# Java - Class<? extends Collection>

Tags: java, class, jackson

I would like to add multiple class in below jackson deserialize. But how do i do that? below is the sample code.

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
mapper.registerModule(module);
AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
Class<? extends Collection> list;
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructRawCollectionType(list);
File is = new File("myXMLFile.xml");
ArtworkContentMessageType je = mapper.readValue(is,mapType);
```

below part is confusing me. How to add class to list?

```
Class<? extends Collection> list;
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructRawCollectionType(list);
```

how do i add multple class(ex: Body.class and P.class). I try below and its not the right object because its not a Class type.

```
List<Class> clazz = new ArrayList<>();
clazz.add(ArtworkContentMessageType.class);
clazz.add(Body.class);
clazz.add(P.class);
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructRawCollectionType(clazz);
```

Comment: Unsure what you're asking. Is it about List<Class> or about Class<? extends Collection> ??

Comment: @ChrisNeve its about Class<? extends Collection> type.

Answer (score 1):

[java.lang.Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a generic class, meaning it can take parameters, as per this syntax:

```
Class<T>
```

where T is the type of the class modeled by the Class object. Taking the same example as in the documentation, the type of `String.class` is `Class<String>`.

As such, by using the [wildcard syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), you can declare an instance of a `Class` without knowing its type: `Class<?>`.

If you don't know the type but you know it will extend a given class, you can use this syntax: `Class<? extends Superclass>`.

So this syntax:

```
Class<? extends Collection> list;
```

declares a class whose type is a subclass of `Collection`.

Comment: Can you give example for "declares a class whose type is a subclass of Collection." ? i still not clear on this.

Comment: Are you familiar with inheritance notion in Java? A class (called subclass or child class) can extend another class (called parent class or superclass) using extends keyword.