# Use Class<? extends Collection> as a method signature

Tags: java, collections, wildcard, extends, generic-type-parameters

In the method signature, I need a parameter that is any class type that extends from Collection (List, Set, etc), so I can return any of them.

To try to achieve this I did use the following method:

```
public Collection<T> method(Class<? extends Collection> collectionType) {
    // Do something...
}
```

However when I try to use it like:

```
method(List.class);
```

The following error arises:

```
Error: java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<java.util.List> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<java.util.Collection>
```

I did search for an answer already solved in Stackoverflow, finding this post: [Java - Class<? extends Collection>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459073/java-class-extends-collection)

But it does not help me to understand the error. I think I'm not understanding the wildcard (?) usage.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Does the method actually take `Class<Collection>` instead (not `Class<? extends Collection>`)?

Comment: Why not pass in a `Supplier` of the relevant type?

Comment: I do have `Class<? extends Collection>` written in the method signature but the IDE I'm using (IntelliJ) marks the method as it expects `Class<Collection>` when using it on my test class. Why does this occur? @Sweeper

Comment: I did change the method signature to try the `Supplier` option as @AndyTurner suggested. This time, the error states that the rquired type must be `Supplier<Class<? extends Collection>>`, but `Supplier<Class<List>>` was provided.

Comment: No, not `Supplier<Class<...>>`, `Supplier<C>`, where `C` is a type variable bounded by `Collection`.

Comment: In my use case, I need `Class<...>` because I want to use it to create instances of `Collection` with the Jackson method `objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType()`, which accepts `(Class<? extends java.util.Collection> collectionClass, Class<?> elementClass`. The idea is to transform `elementClass` collection to the specific subiterface desired. @AndyTurner

Comment: Wanting to pass a `Class` is a bad idea, because they are always rawly-typed (i.e. `Collection`, not `Collection<String>`). If what you want to do is to create a `Collection<E>`, pass in a thing which will _give you_ a `Collection<E>`, not merely a `Collection`, which you then have to unsafely cast in order to get it non-rawly typed.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing it like you just proposed and solved the issue with some little changes. @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `Class<? extends Collection>` is, in fact, correct. The problem that I had did refer to the return type of the method, not being able to cast `Collection<T>`to `List<T>`.